# Correct uses of Perfect continuous Tense

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect, indian-english, sequence-of-tenses

Between them which one is right?

> 1. Indira Banerjee who was the Chief Justice of Madras, **has** recently been elevated to Apex Court.
> 2. Indira Banerjee who was the Chief Justice of Madras, **had** recently been elevated to Apex Court.

Comment: Neither is orthographically valid, because ***who was the Chief Justice of Madras*** is an optional *parenthetical* clause - so it must be set off by commas *before **and** after*. As to whether the word ***court*** should be capitalised or not, that depends entirely on exactly what Apex court (or Apex Court) refers to. Is it a two-word "proper noun" or not? I've no idea. All I can say is that a possibly similar referent in Britain would be referenced differently: *That judge has been transferred to **the Old Bailey** court* (where "court" wouldn't usually be included anyway).

Comment: @FumbleFingers's points apart, tense-wise, both are valid, although suitable to different cases. Moreover, even _Indira Banerjee, who was the Chief Justice of Madras, **was** recently elevated to Apex Court_ is possible.

Comment: Both are right but they mean different things. Also, chief justice [no caps without the name] of the X Court. By the way, there is no perfect continuous in either.

Comment: And these are not in the Perfect Continuous, they are the Perfect forms of the Passive.

Comment: When I search for **"apex court"** as a quoted string, Google tells me about two popular "related" queries: *What is known as **the Apex Court** of India?* and *Is the Supreme Court called **an APEX court** also?* So I'm still no clearer on exactly what the referent is here (specifically, whether *[the] **Apex Court*** is a recognised "proper noun" or not).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, Supreme Court is called The Apex Court of India.

Comment: AbhijitDan - The standard orthography there is *...called **the** Apex Court of India* - same as *Fifty years ago the Empire State Building of New York was the world's tallest skyscraper* (we don't normally capitalise ***the*** in such contexts). But as I said before, whether to capitalise ***court*** depends entirely on whether you're using ***Apex Court*** as a "proper noun" (the established name of one specific entity), or whether ***Apex court*** is simply a two-word collocation identifying one court (the Apex one) out of many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example sentences, both are correct, but it depends how you want to use them

> Indira Banerjee, who was the Chief Justice of Madras, **has** recently been elevated to *(the)* Apex court.

Is fine by itself to refer to a recent event, whereas

> Indira Banerjee, who was the Chief Justice of Madras, **had** recently been elevated to *(the)* Apex Court.

Feels like it is missing something

> Indira Banerjee who was the Chief Justice of Madras, **had** recently been elevated to *(the)* Apex Court *when the new party was voted into power*.

You could also use

> Indira Banerjee, who **had been** the Chief Justice of Madras, **was** recently elevated to *(the)* Apex court.

Comment: That would been the correct variant to include the extra information, using past perfect and simple past to order events.